# Can I enter Mexico by land and go back to the US with an esta?

Tags: usa, esta, us-visa-waiver-program, mexico

I'm an Italian citizen visiting the US with an ESTA. I want to go to Mexico for a day trip with some friends and then go back to the US.

We'll cross into Mexico from San Diego by land and go back the same way.

I have a plane from San Diego to Italy a few days later and my 90-days stamp will still be valid for more than 2 months.

Will I have any problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no issue with your Visa Waiver when you enter by land.  According to [CBP](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1258/~/esta---traveling-to-u.s.-by-land) you don't even need ESTA.  So as long as your Waiver clock still has some time on it see [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42194/land-crossing-to-america-from-mexico-with-esta-90-days-reset?rq=1) or [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/60819/if-someone-is-visiting-the-us-under-esta-for-90-days-goes-to-mexico-for-another?rq=1) you should not have an issue.