# ESTA (Going to Mexico and the US)

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, mexico, swiss-citizens

I am a Swiss citizen. I am planning on going to San Diego from Zurich on November 8-15. Would I be able to do a day-trip to Tijuana and then come back? The trip to Mexico would be by land.

Would I be eligible to re-enter the US?

Thank you!

Comment: Also https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/77328/can-i-enter-mexico-by-land-and-go-back-to-the-us-with-an-esta?rq=1

Comment: @Gerrit That one is outdated

Comment: @Coke How is that outdated?

Comment: @Midavalo Because it says that you don't Need an ESTA, but will Need an I-94W form. The truth is that at Major crossings, ESTA holders don't Need an I-94W form

Comment: @Coke: Go ahead and write a better answer to the original question, then.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can, as you haven't overstayed your allowed 90 days (which cannot be restored by going to Mexico).

Contrary to the answer in the suggested dupe, if you do have an ESTA you'll not need to fill out an I-94W either.

Comment: Crossing land-border into the US requires an I-94, not ESTA.  The asker should already have an I-94 issued on admission into the US from Zurich.  https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1132/~/citizen-of-visa-waiver-country%2C-wants-to-drive-into-u.s.-from-canada-or-mexico%2C

Comment: @Midavalo Wrong. ESTA holders do **not** need the I-94W at major crossings (including Tijuana)

Comment: @Midavalo the I-94 created in connection with ESTA is an [electronic database record](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov).  When a VWP traveler who does not hold ESTA enters by land, they get a paper I-94A form printed for them in connection with the creation of the database record, but if the traveler has active ESTA authorization, the database record is created from that instead.  As far as I can tell, the I-94W is no longer in regular use.  See https://www.cbp.gov/travel/international-visitors/i-94-instructions.

Comment: @phoog I understand that, however you still require a valid (not expired) I-94 to cross the border.  If you have an electronic one issued when you land, then you won't be asked for one when you cross the border.  But if you *don't* have one then ESTA doesn't automatically waive your need to get one.  You'll be asked to complete an I-94W if there is no current electronic I-94 record, whether you have ESTA or not.  Charge is $6 at the border (including Tijuana).

Comment: From CBP (via email today): *If entering by land, you will complete processing upon arrival with the physical form I-94W (6 U.S. dollars). No action is required prior to arrival at the port of entry.  Even if you have a valid ESTA you will be required to complete the form I-94W upon arrival at any land port of entry.*

Comment: @Midavalo apparently you are correct.  My recollection of another answer on this site was faulty, or maybe my recollection of an incorrect answer on this site was accurate, but if that's true I didn't find the incorrect answer when I looked for it.

Comment: @phoog Neither, those recollections were correct. It's the same with APC: CBP provides generalised answers on who can use it, but in practice it varies from POE to POE

Comment: @Midavalo That officer was wrong in that case. CBP officers at Tijuana, the Vancouver Train Station and Blaine have confirmed to me on the phone that ESTA holders do not need the form. When entering from the Toronto area by road, ESTA holders will get a pre-printed form, last time I asked